# Select a sum in Knex.js without using .raw

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I am trying to rewrite some MySQL queries in Knex.js, and I feel like I'm running into `.raw` at every turn, which feels counter to the reason I want to use Knex in the first place.

**Is it possible to write the following query *without* using `.raw`?**

```
SELECT
   product,
   SUM(revenue)
FROM orders
```

Using raw, it works to write:

```
knex()
   .select(
      'product',
      knex.raw('SUM(revenue)')
   )
   .from('orders')
```

but the idea of using Knex was to avoid using MySQL query strings, so I'm hoping there's another way. Or does everyone just use `.raw` everywhere, and I'm misunderstanding something? Very possible, I'm new to this.

Comment: You will need to use `knex.raw` quite often when you write queries using casting or SQL functions. There is nothing bad using it, but you should have used `??` identifier binding to refer columns / tables like this: `knex.raw('SUM(??)', ['revenue'])`  :)

Comment: What's the advantage of that approach? Just shorter sql strings?

Comment: It adds automatically correct quotes to identifiers depending on used sql dialect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `sum` method.

> sum — .sum(column|columns|raw) Retrieve the sum of the values of a
>   given column or array of columns (note that some drivers do not
>   support multiple columns). Also accepts raw expressions.
>
> ```
> knex('users').sum('products')
> Outputs:
> select sum("products") from "users"
> ```

Probably be something like this:

```
knex()
   .select('product')
   .sum('revenue')
   .from('orders')
```

You should adjust to your specific case. You might need to use something like `groupBy('product')` to get total revenue per product.

You should really go over knex's [documentation](https://knexjs.org/), it's pretty good and straight forward and you definitely should not be using raw all the time.

Comment: Ah yes, that will do it! I did see `sum` in the docs, but in my head the sum is inside the select, and I couldn't figure how to make that happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can even specify the returning sum column name like this:

```
knex(tableName)
 .select('product')
 .sum({ total: 'revenue' })
 .groupBy('product');
```